# Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) is returning different paths in different location

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

when i use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)`  in appDelegate of .ios project , i get a path say path1.

same code when used in .core  project , the path i get is different path than path1 .

Can anyone explain, why the paths are different when same code is used in two different solutions .
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each iOS application runs in a **sandbox** and (at least on device) cannot access files from other applications.

So on iOS what `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)` gives you is where you can store user data for the application.

If you run this outside from iOS (no sandbox) then you'll get a shared location (that varies per operating system).

Comment: Thanks that explains it very well

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/